# How to get continuation token to pass in GetConversationsAsync?

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot service to integrate with Microsoft Teams. I am new so I found difficulties to sort things out.

Here is the C# code and the string value was the continue token.

```
var convo = ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).GetConversationsAsync(turnContext, "", cancellationToken);
```

Comment: you don't explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I would like a straightforward answer of where to get the Continuation token so I could pass it on the GetConversationAsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetConversationsAsync` uses the [Get Conversations API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#get-conversations). This API must be called many times in sequence in order to retrieve all the conversations a bot has participated in. The continuation token is used to help each call continue where the last one left off. Therefore, the first call needs no continuation token. For each subsequent call, you should use the continuation token from the [conversations result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#conversationsresult-object) returned by the previous call.

Comment: Awesome sir, so I have to set an empty string for the first call and the following will have to use the return ConversationsResult which contains the property ContinuationToken to pass in the next call right?.

Comment: Yes, but I'd use `null` rather than an empty string

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `GetConversationReference` to pass in the `GetConversationsAsync` and you can check in this links

[GetConversationReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activity.getconversationreference?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

[GitHub sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples)